# Show webcam / camera stream with delay - webrtc

Tags: javascript, camera, webrtc, webcam, getusermedia

I've made a simple setup, getting the webcam / phone camera stream and the passing it on , drawing on a html 2d canvas.

But ive been having trouble figuring out how to show the stream with a delay of few seconds. Kinda like a delay mirror.

I tried playing with `ctx.globalAlpha = 0.005;` but this gives me a ghosting effect rather than 'delaying' the stream.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

- The snippet below doesnt work here probably because of security issues apparently but here's a pen:

https://codepen.io/farisk/pen/LvmGGQ

```js
  var width = 0, height = 0;
  
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  
  var video = document.createElement('video'),
      track;
  video.setAttribute('autoplay',true);
  
  window.vid = video;
  
  function getWebcam(){ 
  
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
 

      var videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
      var newStream = new MediaStream(stream.getVideoTracks());

      video.srcObject = newStream;
      video.play();
      track = stream.getTracks()[0];

    }, function(e) {
      console.error('Rejected!', e);
    });
  }
  
  getWebcam();
  
  var rotation = 0,
      loopFrame,
      centerX,
      centerY,
      twoPI = Math.PI * 2;
  
  function loop(){
    
    loopFrame = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        
    // ctx.globalAlpha = 0.005;
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.restore();

  }
  
  function startLoop(){ 
    loopFrame = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function(){
    width = canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    height = canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    centerX = width / 2;
    centerY = height / 2;
    startLoop();
  });
  
  canvas.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if ( track ) {
      if ( track.stop ) { track.stop(); }
      track = null;
    } else {
      getWebcam();
    }
  });
```

```css
video,
canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

- The snippet below doesnt work here probably because of security issues apparently but here's a pen:

https://codepen.io/farisk/pen/LvmGGQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buffer your stream, and play what you've buffered.

To achieve this with a `MediaStream`, you can make use of the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/), along with the [MediaSource API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource).

The basic idea is to record your stream as it goes, and at each new chunk produced, buffer it into the `MediaSource`. Then we just have to wait for the delay we want with the video paused before starting its playback.

```js
(async () => {
  const delay = 3000;
  const mimeType = `video/webm; codecs="vp8"`;
  const stream = await getStream();
  document.getElementById("realtime").srcObject = stream;
  const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
  const delayed = document.getElementById("delayed");
  delayed.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
  await new Promise((res) =>
    mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", res, { once: true })
  );
  const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeType);
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType });
  const chunks = [];
  recorder.ondataavailable = async ({ data }) => {
    if (mediaSource.readyState !== "open" || !data.size) {
      return;
    }
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(await data.arrayBuffer());
  };
  delayed.pause();
  recorder.start(50);
  setTimeout(() => delayed.play(), delay);
})();

function getStream() {
  // StackSnippet only:
  // because StackSnippet don't allow the use of gUM
  // we return a MediaStream from a simple <canvas> anim
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "30px sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

  function anim() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0], canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
  anim();
  return canvas.captureStream();
}
```

```html
Realtime:<br>
<video id="realtime" autoplay muted controls></video><br> Delayed:<br>
<video id="delayed" autoplay muted controls></video>
```

And [as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3a4b5cmu/) since StackSnippets are not very gUM friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider storing the video data you get in an array of sorts. It might mean delaying the playback for n seconds at first.

Basically on frame 1, you store the video feed into an array, and draw nothing. This happened until frame 1000 (1 second). At that point start drawing based on the first element of the array.

Once you draw that frame, remove it from the array and add the new frame.

Comment: I implemented this solution, but it seems terribly slow (and also convoluted in principle) to draw, store and redraw image data to canvas with a delay. Is there a way to delay the display on the video element itself?